# How to get the bytes that an unsigned integer is composed of?

Tags: lua

Supposing I've this number:

```
local uint = 2000;
```

how can I get the bytes that it's composed of? For instance:

```
print(sepbytes(uint));
-- 7, 208
```

**My try:**

```
local function sepbytes(cur)
  local t = {};
  repeat
    cur = cur / 16;
    table.insert(t, 1, cur);
  until cur <= 0
  return table.unpack(t);
end

print(sepbytes(2000));
```

**This results in:**

```
0   9.8813129168249e-324, +(lots of numbers)...
```

**Expected result:**

```
7, 208
```

Comment: You could try using bit-shifting instead (in Lua 5.3)... `print((2000 & (0xff << 8)) >> 8)` and `print(2000 & 0xff)`

Comment: @ajcr Nice solution, I've been answered in another site with the same (the  difference is that it's using bit32 library). You can post it as an answer if u want

Comment: Lua 5.3 `uint = 2000; print(string.pack(">I2", uint):byte(1,-1))`

Answer (score 1):

Basing in the comments, if I want 2 fixed bytes (that's the current case), I may use **@ajcr** solution:

```
local function InParts(num)
    return ((num & (0xff << 8)) >> 8), (num & 0xff);
end
```

**@EgorSkriptunoff** (Lua 5.3) solution works for any amount of bytes.

```
local function InParts(num)
    return string.pack(">I2", uint):byte(1, -1);
end
```